# Why are these claims appearing like this, when using OpenID connect in ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I get 2 claims which appear in the following way:

```
Claim type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider - Claim value: local - Claim valueType: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
Claim type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences - Claim value: pwd - Claim valueType: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string
```

Why is their type set to the microsoft one, rather than the type IdentityServer does checks against? (`System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` which is equal to `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier`)

And why do all 3 links point to a dead-end? Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's a reference telling you what claims are available, as mentioned in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301737/what-are-the-urls-for-in-claim-types/44307473#44307473). E.g. Google as some of its own, Microsoft has and so on. That's why IdentityServer needs to map the claim to a 'local' type so it is a constant within the system.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg yeah but everything else is written normally (sub, emaile etc) only those 2 stand out in that ugly form. Also, identity server claim differentiates between those. Do I need to do something, or OpenID connect maps them to that microsoft schema? Meaning when the request hits identity server, the claims are written by using `schema.xmlsoap` rather than `schemas.microsoft`?